# Show pop up using script manager

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to make a page in asp.net where user is registering and a new employee id is generated. I need to show the newly generated id using popup  and redirect the user to someother page using `response.redirect()`. In this case javascript is not working.

I am not allowed to use ajax.

Comment: can you add your sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working code..

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "showpopup();", true);
```

where  showpopup(); is a javascript function..

**Script**:

```
 function showpopup() {
    $("#popup").fadeIn('slow');
 }
```

Where popup is the ID of the  div which you are going to display as popup.You can design a div as per your requirements..

Comment: This function work fine when i don't call Response.Redirect() function after showing pop up, but when i write response.redirect() the it redirect me to the next page without showing pop up

Comment: If u use Response.Redirect after showing the popup then popup will not be visible or u will be redirected to the page u wish.Better add a button inside the popup and in click of that button use Response.Redirect..